# Receiving Error in Rest API

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, post, network

We are trying to send post request to salesforce form different system.

But sometimes we get below errors

While Authenticating

> [2022-09-26T12:05:28.935Z] "POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 503 UC,URX upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_termination} ':status', '503'

While sending Post request

> [2022-09-26T12:05:29.884Z] "POST /services/apexrest/ProvSubscriberResponse HTTP/1.1" 503 UC,URX upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_termination}

This error is intermittent and we get so many times and It occurs at the time of authentication as well.

Comment: Well, connection reset/termination is a (computer/IP) networking issue, and probably not something this site is going to be able to help you with (networking is not something most Salesforce users need to worry about). You're going to need to find someone in your organization who has knowledge of networking (and, specifically, knowledge about your organization's network). The first place I would look at is any network proxies that are in place.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/response_code_details

The upstream connection was reset after a response was started. This may include further details about the cause of the disconnect.

So theoretically your upstream is closing the connection before it sends any part of the response.